# Design of simple disassembler

Tags: design

I am writing a simple x86 disassembler in c++ and I would like to hear an input on class which will handle disassembly. I thought to make a class which would receive a pointer to the table which will contain instruction description. In that way I would have logic implemented in a class which could disassemble code for any platform by just receiving different input table. Do you think that's a good way to solve a problem, or should I put the table definition inside a class and then have special classes for x86 disassembler, arm disassembler and so on. I'm a student and I didn't worry before about code elegance but I'm trying to write more elegant code now so any advice about design is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to write a [Recursive Descent Parser (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) then a general-purpose description of the machine code to be disassembled *might* be feasible, but even that is debatable, and you are certainly going to be getting into some very deep waters by just trying that.

If you are not going to be writing a recursive descent parser, then there is probably no point at all in trying to make it so general-purpose.

I would recommend that you first get your disassembler to work in a hard-coded way for a single CPU, and *afterwards* worry about making it general-purpose.  Try to be focused to a single, simple goal, or else you will never get anything done.

Most chances are, ***YAGNI***.  (Ya Ain't Gonna Need It.)